# How to interpret Fourier transform?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, fourier-series

I am very new to this topic.

I ran a Fourier transform with the scipy fft function.

I than plotted the return values:

[image]

I am assuming the x-axis means how many cycles there are in all the data and y-values are the amplitudes at that number of cycles.

I have a time-series that I want to decompose into cycles. How do I use the information from this graph. The biggest amplitude is in the first example but I am assuming this doesn't matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting frequencies from FFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/extracting-frequencies-from-fft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer on original post] Do not hesitate to display the signal and your Fourier transform. It is important to check the soundness of using a Fourier transform, for instance with questions like:

- is your signal long enough?
- can we expect some stationarity?
- should we first remove artifacts that could disturb interpretation, and how?

Here, I can only wonder on:

- the x-axis index seems integer, with no apparent trace of the sampling frequency: keep track of it in the signal and Fourier representation:
- the signal is not zero-average (first peak at 0), so it could be useful to remove the mean (zero-order average), and maybe higher order drifts (slope, or more) before going any further: those can affect the frequency interpretation a lot, for so many reasons
- the shortness: with an index topping at 140, maybe the signal is less than 300 samples. maybe a little preprocessing could be useful: windowing, smoothing, etc.

Thus being said, on a restricted experience:

- around indices 20 and 85, some local peak concentration may deserve further investigation.
- it seems that the spectrum has some relatively fast "average decay" with frequencies.
- yet, the fluctuations are somehow important, perhaps a consequence of insufficient preprocessing, or noise to harness.

Some additional information and updates on your post could be worthwhile.